# Where to set transitioningDelegate other than prepareForSegue:?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm testing some custom transitioning betweens view controllers. As usual, I set the transition protocols in the `prepareForSegue:` method. Everything worked well until I wondered if we could set this anywhere else? I tried creating a view controller and set the delegate programmatically but it didn't work. The presented view controller still uses the default transitioning.

```
let popup = JopUpViewController()
    popup.transitioningDelegate = PopupTransition()
    self.presentViewController(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I tried to create a class function and after `init` the view controller, I set the delegate but it didn't work also.

```
    class func create() -> JopUpViewController {
        let popup = JopUpViewController()
        popup.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
        popup.transitioningDelegate = PopupTransition()
        return popup
}
```

Anyone know how to set the transitioning delegate other than in `prepareForSegue:`?

Answer (score 3):

You must hold the delegate as a property, otherwise it will deallocate, and turn to nil.

```
let popupTransition = PopupTransition()

 class func create() -> JopUpViewController {
        let popup = JopUpViewController()
        popup.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
        popup.transitioningDelegate = self.popupTransition
        return popup
    }
```

Now you can set the delegate wherever you prefer.